# Best way in clojure to return a seq, or nil if its empty

Tags: clojure

Is there a better way to implement this?

```
(if (empty? a-seq)
    nil
    a-seq)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the function [seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq) it does exactly that.

Comment: `not-empty` is using seq internally, which is fine. But not if the seq type matters, which is what I asked for in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know how I missed it in the docs, but [not-empty](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/not-empty) does exactly that (thank you 
Guillermo for making me re-read the docs).